# Android: How to put github library into project

Tags: java, android, listview, github, pull-to-refresh

I want to put LoadMore/PullToRefresh feature to my app via [this](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore/tree/c4a076d938d49a7c449f9a1b927ff730c7139d6b) library made by shontauro. I've tried it like it's said to be done in README, but I think that something is missing there. I don't understand the logic at all. I've put some libraries to my projects in the past (appcompat support library, other .jar libraries etc.) but I didnt figure out what is the system of this type of libraries.

Do you have any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you downloaded the library from Github, you have to add it to the Eclipse workspace.

Go to `File -> Import` and Choose `Android -> Existing Android Code` Into Workspace. Now you will see this dialog:

[image: Import dialog]

To import the library properly you have to:

1. Choose folder of the library
2. Select the library
3. Click finish

Now the library is in your workspace.

You have to add the library to your project. Right click on your project and choose `Properties`. Then go to Android settings.

[image: Android settings eclipse]

Here you can add the library to your project by clicking on `Add...`.

If the library isn't listed in the dialog after you clicked on add, then you have to mark the library as library. Go to the Android project settings for the Library and check `Is Library`.

Answer (score 0):

The `pulltorefresh-and-loadmore/` inside that repository contains [an Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects). If you download the source code for the project, you can attach it as a library to application projects, such as in [Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject).